# Codeigniter dynamically change to undefined Database

Tags: codeigniter

I need to connect to a DB that has not been defined in the database.php config file.

It has not been defined because there are over 200 possible databases.

I will loop through my clients table to get their client code that will determine which database will be in use at the moment.

I generate the db name with a string inside the loop like this:

```
$db_name = "db_".$row['code'];
```

From this, I need to connect to a new DB which will loop through the tables of the DB to check if this DB and the master DB are synchronized.

I tried the following code, but it does not seem to work:

```
$this -> db -> database = $db_name;
```

and I also tried to define a blank connection in the config like this:

```
$db['temp'] = $db['default'];
$db['temp']['database'] = "";
```

and then change to the generated DB name with the

```
$this -> db -> database = $db_name;
```

function, but did not work.

I am not  sure if this is at all possibe, but this was all I could find on how to switch DB connections.

If you have any alternative suggestions, please let me know.

Thanx is advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**switching**](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html#connecting-to-multiple-databases) of Databases you may have found in the [CodeIgniter Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html#connecting-to-multiple-databases) is probably the only, sensible way of obtaining the information without heavily bloating the config files. So hypothetically speaking:

```
$db_config = array(
    //Shared values
    'hostname' => '...',
    'dbdriver' => '...';
);

$all_results = array();

$getDatabases = $this->database_model->get_databases();
foreach( $getDatabases as $key => $row )
{
    $client_db = null;
    $db_forge  = null;

    $db_name   = "db_". $row['code'];

    //Use copy of shared DB Values.
    $active_config = $db_config;
    $active_config['database'] = $db_name;

    $client_db = $this->load->database( $active_config, TRUE );
    $db_forge  = $this->load->dbforge( $client_db, TRUE );

    $result = 
       $client_db->select( "*" )
                 ->get_where( "TB_EXAMPLE", array( "client_id" => '...' ))->row();

    //Example of reason to drop the table
    if ( !empty( $result ) && $result->INACTIVE == TRUE )
    {
         $db_forge->drop_table( "TB_EXAMPLE" );
    }

    //Now finished with this connection to this particular Database.
    $client_db->close();
    $all_results[] = $result;
}
```

However this is pretty ill-advised. It'll obviously connect to 200 different databases, intensive and expensive. If they are all on the same server; it would be better to `SELECT` by different databases, than instead connecting to them.

Comment: Thanx! all that this function will do is loop through the tables and their fields to check is the table is up to date. so I will only be connected to one DB at a time, but there is no way for me to manually connect to each db, so I want this to happen in the loop

Comment: this actually worked perfectly, but you dont by any chance know how to use dbforge with the above, because `$client_db -> dbforge ->drop_table()` and `$client_db ->drop_table()` does not seem to work

Comment: You'd need to separately load the `dbforge` library, after the `load->database` it appears to suggest in the docs. Then it would be `$this->dbforge->drop_table( 'name' );` - I'll edit in the answer :)